# Error Static Injector: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[GameService -> HttpClient]

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a problem with a library in Angular. I have done a library where I ask an API with HttpClient but there's a problem, when I try to go on a class from this library, GameService, I receive: "Error Static Injector: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[GameService -> HttpClient]". When I saw that, I tried to import HttpModule inside my application and add in providers HttpClient but nothing changed.
Here's the code of my class library:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Game } from './model/game';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { EndPointGetterService } from '../utilities/end-point-getter.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GameService {

  private gameUrl = localStorage.getItem('endpoint') + '/Games';
  private headers: HttpHeaders;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private EPGetter: EndPointGetterService) {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
    });
  }
  getStateGame(groupName: string): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.get<number>(this.EPGetter.getEndPointUrl() + '/Games/' + groupName + '/State', { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

And inside my application I have this inside my app.module.ts:

```ts
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { GameService } from '@oneroomic/oneroomlibrary';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    LockscreenComponent,
    SettingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpClient,
    GameService
  ],
```

and that's how i inject the GameService:

```ts
constructor(
  private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
  private gameService: GameService
  ) {}
```

Comment: HI what is your Angular version?

Comment: And Please remove httpClient and gameservice from provider. it's not required to set here.

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
Error: inject() must be called from an injection context

Comment: That's what I receive when I remove it and My angular Version is 7

Comment: Remove this import { GameService } from '@oneroomic/oneroomlibrary'; from app.module.ts

Comment: It's done :/ I edited too my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189382/discussion-between-shubham-chhapre-and-thelittlewozniak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was I tried to install on local this Library but when I posted on NPM, it worked. So apparently, there's a problem when i try to install in local.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing GameService from providers as you have  **`providedIn: 'root'`**. And HttpClient is not needed there too

Comment: I already test without the GameService inside the Providers and I have another Error

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
Error: inject() must be called from an injection context

Comment: I edited my post to show how I inject in my component

Comment: can you post the component cod etoo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189383/discussion-between-thelittlewozniak-and-sajeetharan).